# custom file attribute ios sdk

Tags: ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I wanted to know if it is possible to create custom file attribute for ios file. Just like NSFileCreationDate I want a new attribute 'compressed'.

I could not find any example to do so. Is it possible??.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. The HFS+ file system supports 'Extended Attributes' (ala metadata tags) that you can add to a file, and later read. This is similar to the old "Resource Fork" in the MacOS 9 filesystem.

Look at 'getxattr(2)' and 'setxattr(2)' - these are C interfaces provided by iOS/OSX. You can find out more here [by Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/03/reading-and-writing-extended-file-attributes/). There are other ObjectiveC wrappers but I couldn't find one just now. You'll have to google around.

Comment: I looked in apple documents The only methods I found is  attributes,
valueForAttribute, valuesForAttributes all of them are ready only nothing to set. Can you please provide example.